# In[] and Out[] in code

Tags: python

Please can somebody explain to me, or point to a reference, what the `In [5]` and `Out[5]` in the following code mean:

```
In [5]: list(set(temp1) - set(temp2))
Out[5]: ['Four', 'Three']
```

Comment: Looks like line markers for input and output.  Where / how are you running this python code?  It's not a part of the python, that's for certain.

Answer (score 4):

That's not python code, its how [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/) shows line codes, in this case is your line 5. In is your input and out is the result of that input.

Answer (score 3):

That's the prompt for [IPython](http://ipython.org/) ... It doesn't have much of a meaning other than to keep track of how many commands you've issued in an IPython session.  Those lines come in pairs (input and output).  Similarly, you'll often see people copy/paste from a normal commandline python session, and then you'll see `>>>` all over the place for input (output doesn't have a `>>>`):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list(set('abc') - set('bc'))
['a']
>>>
```